# Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined at Request._callback

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

WHILE CREATING NEW IONIC APP  I AM GETTING THIS ERROR

```
C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:474
          process.stdout.write('Unable to fetch', err, res.statusCode);
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
        at Request._callback (C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:474:55)
        at self.callback (C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\orcilia49\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:971:8)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This most likely a proxy issue.

Make sure that you are using pc / laptop with direct internet connection.

I hope this solves your issue.

If you are using windows and using cmd to run ionic app then use this command to set your proxy

```
set http_proxy=http://[your proxy servers IP : your proxy servers port]
```

Comment: Hi. I've set the npm config proxy variable and could install cordova and ionic correctly. Now I'm getting the same error cli.js:474. I cannot have direct connection. Must use proxy. Where should I also set the proxy? Thanks

Comment: If you are using windows and using cmd to run ionic app then use this command to set your proxy set http_proxy=http://[your proxy servers IP : your proxy servers port]

Comment: I'm using linux and could solve with this... PROXY=http://myip:port ionic start appname